# Fitting using curve_fit of scipy in python gives totally different answer for 1/t and t

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I was trying to fit some data to a single degree exponential decay function but `a*exp(-x*t)` and `a*exp(-x/t)` gives completely different answers with the latter not at all fitting the data well.
The code:

```
def func(x, a1, t1, c):
    return a1 * numpy.exp(-x*t1) + c

interp_x = np.arange(low,high+dx,dx)
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y,maxfev=10000)
curve = func(interp_x,*popt)
```

This was the data used:

```
0.050   365.104
0.100   331.764
0.200   299.508
0.500   241.281
0.700   188.579
1.000   144.728
2.000   73.2627
```

Comment: What were the initial estimates used in each case?

Comment: @nicoguaro I dd not use any. I just gave the scipy.optimize.curve_fit() and the data as input and used values returned by it, I hope I am clear.

Comment: It may help if you put your full code in the question.

Comment: Why do you expect similar fits from both models?

Comment: @Tyberius I have edit tthe question with the code

Comment: @BrianBorchers The reason I expect them to result in the same fir is that for every t in a*exp(-x*t) there shoulld be a corresponding t in a*exp(-x/t) that fits exactly the same. Especially when t is close to 1. So shouldn't it give the same fits? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something.

Comment: @BrianBorchers What  is it?

Comment: What are the indepedent variables, dependent variables, and parameters in your example?  e.g. is t your independent variable, y your dependent variable and a, x, and c your parameters?

Comment: @BrianBorchers x is independent variable, y is dependent variable and a,t and c are the parameters.

Comment: In that case, the difference is most likely do to the initial parameter that the fitting routine starts with.

Answer (score 3):

Curve fitting can be very sensitive to your initial guess for each parameter. Because you don't specify a guess in your code, all of these parameters start with a value of 1. Comparing with the converged results for the `t` fitting, while `t` is actually pretty close to 1, the other parameters are much further away. Its mostly just luck that the `t` value didn't drift too far away while searching for appropriate values for `a` and `c`.

The `1/t` fit was not so lucky and the search led it far away from the good solution obtained by the `t` fit. However a better initial guess can fix this. Using the `a` and `c` values from the `t` fit as an initial guess leads to the same solutions. I hadn't tried this, but I suspect even just providing a better guess for `c` (say 400) would probably be enough to make both fits match.

In general, you should always try to provide an initial guess for these parameters, especially for cases where there may be multiple distinct sets of parameters that minimize the error of the fit.